# Extracting parameters from a Python F-string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, f-string

I have a python f-string as follows:

```
def send_string():
    ticket_id=123
    message = f'{ticket_id} Jira created successfully'
    return message

def extract_ticket_from_message(message):
    #pseudo code
    # Is it possible to extract the ticket id without parsing the 
    # whole string and using regex
```

Is there a convenient way of extracting the **ticket_id** value from the f-string without having to parse the whole string using regex in Python 3.6?

Comment: Well, the variable `ticket_id` should hold it. I'm guessing that's not what you're looking for... can you expand a bit? Maybe with a little more example code?

Comment: is *"ticket_id"* literally the expected output in your example, or are you expecting a ticket id like *"1234"*? Does the solution need to be generalized? Do we have any garauntees about what *ticket_id* is going to be: i.e.- do we know it won't contain spaces and you can simply use `message.split(maxsplit=1)[0]`?

Comment: Why not simply `yourDesiredResult = str(ticket_id)`? Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @usr2564301, Why not `yourDesiredResult = ticket_id`?

Comment: @Austin: in the formatted f-string it will be a string. It looks like OP is thinking about alternatives to getting its value *as a string*. We will have to await clarification, though.

Comment: @glibdud...The f-string message is passed as a parameter to a function..in that function, i no longer have access to the variable ticket_id without explicitly passing it..

Comment: Can `ticket_id` have spaces in it?

Comment: expanded the question a bit more..@Austin..no spaces in the **ticket_id**

Answer (score 1):

If

```
 ticket_id = 1234
 message = f'{ticket_id} Jira created successfully'
```

then – without using a regex –

```
def extract_ticket_from_message(message):
    return message.split()[0]
```

In other words, the first word. If `ticket_id` can be any string as well (so possibly containing spaces), you can still use this but cut off the final 3 words instead. (After all, you know what will follow.) If `ticket_id` is a more complex object that *results* in a string representation, there is no practical way to resolve it back to the original class/object/anything else than a Python primitive.

Noteworthy: you cannot get the original *type* without ambiguity. If the original was a string *but* its value was `"1234"`, then you cannot know for sure if a string or number was passed.